# What is difference between numpy array.tolist() and scipy.sparse tolist()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
```

using numpy I get

```
test_mat = (np.ones((4,6)))
test_list = test_mat[0,:].tolist()
```

gives `test_list` as a list which has 6 elements. However whe I use scipy.sparse

```
test_mat = lil_matrix(np.ones((4,6)))
test_list = test_mat[0,:].todense().tolist()
```

gives `test_list` as a list which has one element, which in turn has 6 elements (`test_list[0]` has 6 elements).

Can someone explain to me the underlying mechanism which results in this difference?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `lil_matrix.todense()` returns a numpy `matrix`, which always has `ndim = 2`, as opposed to the numpy `ndarray`, which will reduce its dimension when only one row/col is selected in slicing.  The dimensionality of the matrix/array is preserved in the conversion to a list-of-lists format.

To see the 2d behavior in the array either slice it as:

```
test_mat = np.ones((4,6))
test_list = test_mat[0:1,:].tolist()
```

Or, initiate it as:

```
test_mat = np.matrix(np.ones((4,6)))
test_list = test_mat[0:1,:].tolist()
```

And you'll see the 2d list of lists as you do from the `lil_matrix`

Here's what you have *before* you convert to a list:

```
In [137]: ma = np.ones((4,6))

In [138]: mm = np.matrix(np.ones((4,6)))

In [139]: ms = lil_matrix(np.ones((4,6)))

In [141]: ma[0,:]
Out[141]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

In [142]: mm[0,:]
Out[142]: matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [143]: ms[0,:].todense()
Out[143]: matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Using a slice that doesn't reduce dimension:

```
In [144]: ma[0:1,:]
Out[144]: array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The number of square brackets above is the key.  Looking at their shapes:

```
In [145]: ma[0:1,:].shape
Out[145]: (1, 6)

In [146]: ma[0,:].shape
Out[146]: (6,)

In [147]: mm[0,:].shape
Out[147]: (1, 6)

In [148]: ms[0,:].shape
Out[148]: (1, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the implementation of `array` and the dense matrix:
when you index the `array` as in

```
test_list = test_mat[0,:]
```

You cat a new 1D-array.

When, however, you do the same indexing on the sparse matrix, the result is a 1x6 sparse matrix. Note that this is still a 2D matrix, where one dimension happens to be of length 1.

since `tolist()` returns a list that represents the matrix, you get a simple list for the 1D object obtained form the `array` and a 2D "list of lists" containing the rows of the sparse matrix.